# Can matplotlib patches be used with a function?

Tags: python, image-processing, matplotlib

I am attempting to plot a series of .fits images in Python, and apply a thresholding rule so that only high-value pixels are highlighted. My thresholding rule is as follows:

```
threshold = 7000
test = np.greater_equal(cropped_image, threshold)
plt.imshow(test)
```

In this way, I return a black/white image that displays all the pixels greater than threshold values as white, and all pixels lower than threshold as black. 
However, what I would like to do - instead of plotting a separate image - is to overlay a colour above pixels that exceed the threshold value.

I understand that the matplotlib module `patches` is able to overlay colours and shapes on images; however, it appears that `patches` requires the user to input fixed co-ordinate values that will specify where the patch is placed.

My question is, can `patches` be modified so that patches can be placed over pixels exceeding a threshold value? Or is there another module that would achieve this more efficiently? I have not found anything so far.

Many thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use the parameter `alpha` to put your 2nd image as an overlay :

```
threshold = 7000
test = np.greater_equal(cropped_image, threshold)
img1 = plt.imshow(cropped_image)
img2 = plt.imshow(test, alpha=.9)
plt.show()
```

Play with it (and the colormap) to have the display you need.

Comment: Thank you, this worked very well! Is `alpha` the command that creates the overlay?

Comment: `alpha` is the opacity. `alpha=0.9` means 90% opaque, or 10% transparent.